# Why Google Play Store only allows free apps in Myanmar?

Tags: google-play-store

I am an Android developer and noticed that my apps can not be sold in Myanmar (and other countries) - the country appears in the list but with a strikethrough formatting.

I found [a post on XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1787366) asking the same.

Does Google enforce an export restriction of any kind?

Comment: Android developers in Myanmar still are excluded from paid app distribution to their home country in 2015. Any update from Google?

Comment: I updated the title based on current condition (developer can put free apps on Play Store). However, I couldn't find any official statement from Google about paid apps in Myanmar, and thus make this question opinion-based. Also, developer-related question is actually off-topic here, since this site focuses on end-users instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Burma or Myanmar had been sanctioned since 1997 by the U.S. due to the political system. The U.S. plans on lifting the sanctions  starting 2013 because Myanmar began to allow democratic elections (Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burma#Economic_sanctions)). Not all sanctions have been lifted, yet but Google plans on expanding to Myanmar in the future.

From qz.com [here](http://qz.com/65878/here-are-googles-plans-to-put-itself-at-the-core-of-myanmars-nascent-internet-infrastructure/):

> "Google Play… and Google Wallet? The Google Play store, the app store
>   for Android phones, has been blocked in Myanmar because of
>   international sanctions that restrict payments to the country.
>   Instead, locals use pirate app stores, which work with their
>   jailbroken phones. Google plans to open the Google Play store in the
>   near future, and already the country’s app developers report
>   restrictions are coming down."

From the [US Treasory Department sanction document](http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Documents/burma.txt):

> "With certain exceptions, U.S. persons (both individuals and entities)
>   are prohibited from transferring, paying, exporting, withdrawing, or
>   otherwise dealing in the property and interests in property of an
>   individual or entity on OFAC’s list of Specially Designated Nationals
>   and Blocked Persons (“SDN List”), including those listed in the Annex
>   to E.O. 13310, E.O. 13448, and E.O. 13464, or determined by the
>   Secretary of the Treasury [...]"